Tomcat AJP Chocking even before reaching max Threads
We see that AJP shows max threads as 200 but when it reaches 70 threads it start throwing errors in mod_jk.log as below. What is the cause of below error while have plenty of threads available. We haven't explicitly defined any http threads for Worker MPM assuming it will pick up default values.
CPU and memory seems to be good.
Tomcat status shows:

Max threads:200
Current thread count:70
Current thread busy:57

[Sun Apr 28 13:19:56 2024] [warn] ajp_get_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (3372): Unable to get the free endpoint for worker worker4 from 10 slots
[Sun Apr 28 13:19:56 2024] [error] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2928): Could not get endpoint for worker=worker4
[Sun Apr 28 13:19:56 2024] [info] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2991): Service error=0 for worker=worker4

We are not able to figure out root cause of the issue yet. netstat shows very low DB connection and all external calls endpoints are also not high. Not able to figure out where are those 70 threads used and not able to accept more than 70 connections.
